# round image is not fully visible on a certain phone (using "CircularImageView" library)

Tags: android, image

In my application, I am using "[CircularImageView](https://github.com/lopspower/CircularImageView)" library to create a round image.

Everything is working fine but when I try to run the application on galaxy "j7 pro-2017 phone" I am getting a partial picture.

**How it looks  "galaxy j7 pro-2017 phone"**

[image]

**This is the gradle**

```
 implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.0.2'
```

**This is the XML**

```
<com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/detailsLayout"
    android:id="@+id/circularImage"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    app:civ_border_color="#000000"
    app:civ_border_width="1dp"
    app:civ_shadow="true"
    app:civ_shadow_radius="10"
    app:civ_shadow_color="#e4292929"
    android:src="@drawable/no_pictures"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
</com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView>
```

Comment: How should it look like?

Comment: It should be a circle, and on galaxy j7 pro-2017 phone(see above image) it's basically looking like the top left quarter of the round image (it has nothing to do with the size is the image, I have checked this as well)

Comment: Did u try to add: `android:scaleType="centerCrop"`

Comment: I would suggest to set width and height to `wrap_content`. If you need a specific height to the list item. you can set it to it. And also `scale type center Crop`

Comment: android:scaleType="centerCrop" wont fix it , and again , the image size is not the problem(so wrap_content dont help )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ended up using [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide), like this:

```
  Glide.with(context)
    .load(url)
    .apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform())
    .into(imageView);
```